# hide list elements based on related button

Tags: jquery, list, button, hide

I have a simple list generated from a php/mysql query, and every list item has a button to hide the element if clicked:

```
<ul id="mylist">
<li class="item">element 1 <button type="button" id="hideme">hide element</button></li>
<li class="item">element 2 <button type="button" id="hideme">hide element</button></li></ul>
```

I have this working, but I don't want it to hide the element when the element is clicked; I want the button instead:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(".item").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
});
```

edit: what I want to do is to hide all the content of the `<li>`  when the button is clicked, also the button.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to hide button

You can use

```
  $(this).find('button').hide();
```

Additionally `ID` must be unique in HTML.

I would suggest you to use `class` instead of `id`

```
<ul id="mylist">
<li class="item">element 1 <button type="button" class="hideme">hide element</button></li>
<li class="item">element 2 <button type="button" class="hideme">hide element</button></li>  </ul>
```

JavaScript

```
  $(this).find('.hideme').hide();
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/4yE2R/)

### EDIT

If you want hide entire row, use this

```
$(".hideme").click(function () {
    $(this).closest('li.item').hide();
});
```

[**Updated DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/4yE2R/1/)

Comment: sorry for my english :) what i want to do is exactly what you did, but the diference is that i want all the content of the <li> hidden when the button is clicked, also the button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to do what you need:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$(".item").click(function(){
    $(this).find(':button').hide();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the button for the click event and then from the button target it's parent to hide the entire row.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(this).parent('li').hide();
    });
});
```